# Which build.gradle file to put android arsenal libraries in

Tags: android, import, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to use some of the awesome android arsenal libraries. For example: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/703. If you go to main page and the package page it gives instructions on what to add to the build.gradle file. I recently updated Android Studio and the build.grade files are now in the same "Gradle Scripts" Tab. I want to know where to put the lines:

```
// stock actionBar
compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:1.x.x'

// Toolbar and ActionBarCompat-v21 (includes support-v7:21.0.x)
compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.x.x'

// actionBarCompat-v20 (up to support-v7:20.0.0 - does not support Toolbar)
compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-abc:1.x.x'

// actionBarSherlock
compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-abs:1.x.x'
```

and/or

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.balysv:material-menu:v1.5.1'
}
```

I am confused because of the two build.gradle files listed here:
[image: Project Structure]

The Project:Socio file looks like this:
[image: Socio build.gradle]

The Module:app file looks like this:
[image: app build.gradle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all dependencies in the `module/build.gradle` file.

For example

```
compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:1.x.x'
compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.x.x'
compile 'com.github.balysv:material-menu:v1.5.1'
```

About the repositories you can put it in the top level o in module gradle file. It depends if any project uses the same repos.

For example: `root/build.gradle`

```
allprojects{
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven {
         url "https://jitpack.io"
      }
   }
}
```

or `module/build.gradle`

```
      repositories {
          jcenter()
          maven {
             url "https://jitpack.io"
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in the `Module:app` gradle file.

The other gradle file is for project-wide build configuration.  From the documentation:

> Android Studio projects contain a top-level project Gradle build file that allows you to add the configuration options common to all application modules in the project. Each application module also has its own build.gradle file for build settings specific to that module.

Comment: so where is the repository section go in that file?

Comment: I believe that should go in the top-level gradle file.